# Функция get_post() Wordpress не работает

Tags: wordpress

```
global $post;
$args = array('category_name'=>'Marketing Social','tag'=>'social','post_type'=>'any');
$result = get_post($args);
print_r($result);
```

Таксономия Marketing Social существует, имеется метка `social`, существуют 3 записи в БД этой таксономии и под этой меткой. `get_post()` не выводит из БД ничего. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_post` возвращает запись по переданному `id`, в вашем же случае нужно использовать `get_posts` для выборки записей по параметрам

```
$args = [
    'category_name' => 'Marketing Social',
    'tag' => 'social',
    'post_type' => 'any',
];
$result = get_posts($args);
print_r($result);
```

подробнее о функциях [get_post](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post), [get_posts](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts)